# Dynamic config Spring batch execution time and parameters via database configured parameters

Tags: spring-batch, quartz-scheduler

I am a fresh spring batch user, pls help me. Here is my requirement:

1. I have fulfilled several spring batch jobs with different names. I want to execute these jobs  with different job parameters, and I hope these parameters can be configured dynamically in database, so I can add new job execution with different job names and different parameters.
2. Also, I want to schedule my job execution in different time, and the crontab expression can also be configured.

Maybe the database structure is like:

- id
- task_name
- spring_batch_job_name
- cron_expression

Wonder if some guys can guide me. Very thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my job setting entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report_tasks_manager", schema = "reconciliation", catalog = "")
public class ReportTasksManager {
    private int id;
    private String taskDesc;
    private String taskName;
// crontab expression 
    private String cronExpression;
// class name to execute job logic
    private String methodName;
    private int state;
    private Integer conCurrent;
    private String reserved1;
    private String reserved2;
    private String reserved3;
    private Timestamp startTime;
    private Timestamp endTime;
    private Timestamp createTime;
}
```

I defined a class which implemented Job interface, and the execute() method in this class executes the business logic, like launching a spring batch job:

```
public class QuartzJobFactory implements Job {

    public QuartzJobFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("time ={" + new Date() + "}");
        System.out.println("starting job build factory");
        ReportTasksManager reportTasksManager = (ReportTasksManager) jobExecutionContext.getMergedJobDataMap().get("scheduleJob");
        System.out.println("job name = {" + reportTasksManager.getTaskName() + "}");
    }
}
```

For registering a cron trigger, I defined a rest controller to checkout job parameters in database and configure scheduler

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "test")
public class QuartzManager {

    private SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    @Autowired
    private ReportTaskManagerDAO reportTaskManagerDAO;

    @GetMapping(value = "schedule")
    public void scheduleJob() {
//        Read settings from database
        List<ReportTasksManager> quartzList = reportTaskManagerDAO.findAll();
        if (quartzList.size() > 0) {
            quartzList.forEach(reportTasksManager -> {
                try {
                    configQuartz(reportTasksManager, schedulerFactory.getScheduler());
                } catch (SchedulerException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void configQuartz(ReportTasksManager reportTasksManager, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException, ClassNotFoundException {
        TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey(reportTasksManager.getTaskName(), Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);
//        check if triggers already defined in scheduler
        CronTrigger trigger = (CronTrigger) scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
        if (null == trigger) {
//            not define——new trigger&jobDetail
            JobDetail jobDetail =
                    JobBuilder.newJob((Class<? extends Job>) Class.forName(reportTasksManager.getMethodName()))
                            .withIdentity(reportTasksManager.getTaskName(), Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                            .build();
            jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("scheduleJob", reportTasksManager);
            CronScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(reportTasksManager.getCronExpression());
            trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(reportTasksManager.getTaskName(), Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP)
                    .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder)
                    .build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            scheduler.start();
        } else {
//            already defined——update 
            CronScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(reportTasksManager.getCronExpression());
            trigger = trigger.getTriggerBuilder()
                    .withIdentity(triggerKey)
                    .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder)
                    .build();
            scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use create some `Util` class( on `@PostConstruct`) which loads your job config from DB.

**For example:**

```
     @Entity
        public class Configuration{

            @Id 
            private long id;

            private String field;


            private String value;
        // getter and setter

        }


    @Component
    public interface ConfigurationRepo extends JpaRepository<Configuration, Long> {

    }



  public final class ConfigurationUtil {
        private ConfigurationUtil() {

        }

        private static List<Configuration> defaultConfiguration;

        /**
         * @return the defaultConfiguration
         */
        public static List<Configuration> getDefaultConfiguration() {
        return defaultConfiguration;
        }

        /**
         * @param defaultConfiguration the defaultConfiguration to set
         */
        public static void setDefaultConfiguration(List<Configuration> defaultConfiguration) {
        ConfigurationUtil.defaultConfiguration = defaultConfiguration;
        }

        public static String getValueByField(String field) {
        return defaultConfiguration.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getField()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(field))
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getValue();
        }



    }

    @Component
    public class ConfigurationContextInitializer {

        @Autowired
        ConfigurationRepo configurationRepo;



        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
        ConfigurationUtil.setDefaultConfiguration(configurationRepo.findAll()); 


        }
    }

//To access DB value
ConfigurationUtil.getValueByField("JOB_NAME"); // depends on your DB key
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer, I just solved this problem via Quartz:

using parameters to register CronTrigger and JobDetail, add them into scheduler

Comment: @Otailai, thank you for your reply. If possible can you please share your answer so that in future someone might need it :).

Comment: I do not know it is the appropriate way to realize such function, but it works. Hope this helps!